# Create a DataFrame with unique values of a Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new at Python and Pandas and I'm having troubles to solve a problem, I have a DF with multiple variables, as the example bellow:

```
SRC Data1 Data2
AAA  180   122
BBB  168   121
CCC  165   147
DDD  140   156
EEE  152   103
AAA  170   100
CCC  166   112
DDD  116   155
EEE  179   119
```

And I'm expecting something like:

DF_A

```
SRC    Data1   Data2
AAA    180     122
AAA    170     100
```

DF_B

```
SRC    Data1   Data2
BBB     168     121
```

What I need is create a DF to each value in *SRC* and carry their respective data in *Data1* and *Data2*

I have alredy use pd.DataFrame(Example.SRC.unique()) and get each unique values in *SRC* but I don't know if this will help me.

Thank you all!

Comment: please post your desired data set

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Edit your question. Do not post in comments.

Comment: @FelipeAmaralRodrigues almost there - use the [edit] link to add that to your question formatted as you did your input dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The neat way to do this is `dict(iter(g))`:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby("SRC", as_index=False)

In [12]: d = dict(iter(g))

In [13]: d
Out[13]:
{'AAA':    SRC  Data1  Data2
 0  AAA    180    122
 5  AAA    170    100, 'BBB':    SRC  Data1  Data2
 1  BBB    168    121, 'CCC':    SRC  Data1  Data2
 2  CCC    165    147
 6  CCC    166    112, 'DDD':    SRC  Data1  Data2
 3  DDD    140    156
 7  DDD    116    155, 'EEE':    SRC  Data1  Data2
 4  EEE    152    103
 8  EEE    179    119}

In [14]: d["AAA"]
Out[14]:
   SRC  Data1  Data2
0  AAA    180    122
5  AAA    170    100
```

You can pull out the subgroups without copying:

```
In [21]: g.get_group("AAA")
Out[21]:
   SRC  Data1  Data2
0  AAA    180    122
5  AAA    170    100
```

*Note: you can get an iterable of the keys with `g.groups.keys()`.*

Answer (score 3):

I'd generate a dictionary of DFs:

```
In [247]: dfs = {n:g for n,g in df.groupby('SRC')}

In [248]: dfs['AAA']
Out[248]:
   SRC  Data1  Data2
0  AAA    180    122
5  AAA    170    100

In [249]: dfs['BBB']
Out[249]:
   SRC  Data1  Data2
1  BBB    168    121

In [253]: dfs.keys()
Out[253]: dict_keys(['EEE', 'DDD', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'AAA'])
```

a bit nicer way to achieve the same thing:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('SRC')))
```